# Is there any method to see the kml of a Google Earth project

Tags: maps, google-earth

I have a Google Earth project which contains a customized map. I wish to open the map in android studio but that requires me to use the kml file of the map. How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're working in the "new" version of Google Earth on the web/browser (not the Earth Pro desktop version).  If so, when you have your project open, click the 3-dot menu at the top of the projects panel, and you should see an option to "Export as KML file".

[image]